# How to return variable from Axios Response in Composition API to root level?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I want to return the `headings` array from an `axios.get` function and use it on `root level` inside my `vue component` but when I try to return it, it shows:

```
ReferenceError: headings is not defined
```

This is the `script element` from my `Vue3 Component`:

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';

const homePage = ref({
    heading: "",
    content: "",
    image: ""
});

axios.get('/home')
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.data[res.data.length - 1]
        const headings = {
            en: data['heading_(en)'],
            de: data['heading_(de)'],
            ar: data['heading_(ar)'],
        }
        return headings;
    })

console.log(headings);

</script>
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to **Thomas** and **huan feng** I can do this:

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from 'vue';

const state = reactive({
    headings: {},
    content: {},
    image: ""
})

axios.get('/home')
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.data[res.data.length - 1]

        state.headings = {
            en: data['heading_(en)'],
            de: data['heading_(de)'],
            ar: data['heading_(ar)'],
        }

        console.log(state.headings.en)
    })

</script>
```

This is the most elegant solution because `reactive` objects provide the cleanest framework when working with arrays. Call it from the `vue component` like so:

```
    <h2>{{ state.headings.en }}</h2>
```

Since `axios` is `asynchronous` returning the variable into `root level` is more difficult and in my case not necessary. I can output it inside `then`.

Comment: `headings` isn't defined. You'll need to have a `const headings = ref(null)` and then not returning it but assigning it in the `then`. And the log statement will be executed immediately and not waiting for the axios response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Better to wrap page states in a reactive object
const state = reactive({
    headings: []
})

axios.get('/home')
.then(res => {
    const data = res.data[res.data.length - 1]
    state.headings = {
        en: data['heading_(en)'],
        de: data['heading_(de)'],
        ar: data['heading_(ar)'],
    };
})
// Use state.headings before this line,
// Unpack it and you can directly use headings in template 
const {headings} = toRefs(state);
```

Comment: I think I didn't make my problem clear enough. I don't need to use the variable globally in the whole project, only in this component. Maybe `global` was the wrong word for it.

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, now I can access the content of `state`. There is just a small problem, for whatever reason I can access it like so `console.log(state)` which outputs the whole object but not like so `console.log(state.headings)` although the `state` object has a child called `headings`. It returns undefined. Any idea?

Comment: Where did you console log the state? after assigning the axios reponse to state.headings?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

```
<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue';

const homePage = reactive({
    headings: {},
    content: '',
    image: ''
});

axios.get('/home')
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.data[res.data.length - 1]
        homePage.headings = {
            en: data['heading_(en)'],
            de: data['heading_(de)'],
            ar: data['heading_(ar)'],
        }
    })

</script>
```

And I suggest using reactive for objects.

EDIT: applying the response to the `homePage` reactive object.

Comment: Hello, this approach works but is there a way to assign the variable directly to const `homePage = ref({
    heading: "",
    content: "",
    image: ""
});` instead of `const headings`? My problem is that I have many such `fields` and it would be great if I could send them to a `ref array` directly.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov can you please expand your question a bit then? I am still not sure what you want. Or is this `heading` in the `homePage` object actually an array and should be called `headings`?